# SQL Statement to Single Entity Core Data Fetch Request

Tags: mysql, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a single `Entity` in `CoreData` mimicking a `MySQL` database table with the following structure:

```
Photo
    abv            Double
    photoId        Integer16
    photographer   String
    isActive       Boolean
    lastUpdated    Data
    name           String
```

I can run the following `SQL` statement to get my desired result set:

```
SELECT  `photographerName`, COUNT(`photographerName`) 
FROM  `Photos` 
WHERE  `isActive` LIKE 1
GROUP BY  `photographerName` 
ORDER BY  `photographerName`
```

**What combination of `NSFetchRequest`, `NSSortDescriptor`, `NSPredicate`, `NSExpressionDescription` can I use to achieve the same results in `iOS`?**

I am using the following:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
NSSortDescriptor *photographerSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"photographer" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSPredicate *onlyActivePhotos = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isActive == 1"];

request.sortDescriptors = @[photographerSortDescriptor];
request.predicate = onlyActivePhotos;

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

Which gets me the `isActive` fine, but returns a row for every `Photo`, not `Photographer`.

**Or... should I be splitting this into two `Entities`? For example, `Photographer` with a one-to-many relationship to `Photos`?**

Comment: `photographerName` -> `photographer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is certainly better and more flexible design to have a relationship `Photo`-`Photographer`.

However, what you want can also be achieved. You can only get the photo entities, so after you have to filter the resulting array to just return your photographer names.

```
NSArray *photographerNames = [fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
   valueForKeyPath:"@photographer"];
NSSet *uniqueNames = [NSSet setWithArray:photographerNames];
NSArray *orderedNames = [uniqueNames sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
   @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]]];
```

As you can see, this is quite cumbersome. Also, you have lost the information which photos are associated with each photographer.

So please go with the relationship. After all, Core Data is an object graph, not a database wrapper.

Comment: +1 and accept for the last sentence. Went with two `NSEntities`.